# Get String from ArrayList inside an ArrayList inside an ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I need to get three levels down into an array list. Here is my code on how I create the final product "rowList":

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> rowList = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> appList =new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

int Id = -1;
int cc = rsmd.getColumnCount();
while(rs.next()){
    if(Id == -1){
        arr.add(rs.getString("name"));
        Id= Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Id"));
    }
    if(Id!= Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Id"))){
        Id= Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Id"));
        rowList.add(appList);
        appList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        arr.add(rs.getString("name"));

    }

    for(int i=2; i < rsmd.getColumnCount();i++){
        arr.add(rs.getString(rsmd.getColumnName(i)));
    }
    appList.add(arr);
    arr = new ArrayList<>();
}
rowList.add(appList);
```

So in the end rowlist will look something like this:

```
[0]
  [0]
   [0]Property 1
   [1]Property 2
   [2]Property 3
  [1]
   [0]Property 1
   [1]Property 2
   [2]Property 3
[1]
  [0]
   [0]Property 1
   [1]Property 2
   [2]Property 3
  [1]
   [0]Property 1
   [1]Property 2
   [2]Property 3
```

So my question would be how to get to the properties, the last level in the nested array? I can use rowList.get(0).get(0).toString() to return the string array, but rowList.get(0).get(0).get(0) doesn't work, and instead gives the error: cannot find symbol.

I would also like to be able to remove a property after I've retrieved it and set it to a string. That part can easily be worked around though, so it isn't vital.

Comment: The repeated calls to `Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Id"))` are very redundant...

Comment: When I say I get a string array, I mean if I run this: rowList.get(0).get(0).toString(); then I get this:  [Property1, Property2, Property3, Property4]. Does that help?

Comment: Can you show the code which populates `rowList`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I did. 13th line I posted and also the last row. rowList.add(appList);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're using a raw type:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> rowList = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
```

`rowList.get(0)` returns an `ArrayList`. Antoher `.get(0)` will return an `Object`, because you're using a raw type. And `Object` does not have a `get` method.

But `Object` does have a `toString` method, so you can call `toString`.

---

You simply have to change the declaration. This can be made easier using the diamond:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> rowList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> appList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: This works, but you are missing one > right before rowList. Once I confirm I will check you off as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, let's think about the type of each result in the chained calls `rowList.get(0).get(0).get(0)`. The easiest way to do this is to break each call into its own line so that we can figure out the type we need for the variable declaration. First of all, look at the declaration of `rowList`:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> rowList = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
```

This tells us that `rowList.get(0)` will return an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList arr = rowList.get(0);
```

Now `rowList.get(0).get(0)` is equivalent to `arr.get(0)`. But this returns an `Object`:

```
Object obj = arr.get(0);
```

So `rowList.get(0).get(0).get(0)` is equivalent to `obj.get(0)`. However, `Object` does not have a method named `get()`. This is why you get an error message.

In general, you should be very careful when chaining method calls. Typically this syntax is only used when a method returns a reference to the calling object. That way the return type is always the same and much easier to keep track of.  When the return type differs on each successive method call, it can be difficult to keep track of.

The problem is that the `ArrayList` returned by `rowList.get(0)` is a raw type. So another `get()` call only returns an `Object`. You should use generics to specify the type of object in the "rows":

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> rowList = new ArrayList<>();
```

As you see here, generics can be used as the type inside of any `<>` just like you already did for the outermost level of `ArrayList` in your originaly code. (Note that in JDK 7+, you can use the diamond operator when creating an `ArrayList`. This greatly reduces duplicating the type information that already appears in the declaration.)

Better yet, you can declare your variables using the `List` interface in order to provide some flexibility in the concrete type used:

```
List<List<List<String>>> rowList = new ArrayList<>();
```